# Is it possible to perform macOS GUI automation using Java or python?

Tags: python, java, macos, automation

I have a .pkg/.dmg file which provides following operations

1. I can install it
2. After installation there is an option to provide username and password details with some URL to access the server

I want to perform the GUI automation for this application (without using Automator), is it possible to achieve using Java or Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java to create a GUI application that runs on MacOS.
You can use [JPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) to package this application such that it will install natively, so for MacOS it would come as dmg.

But rereading your question, you already have some GUI application and you just want to automatically install and operate it? Then in Java your best bet might be the [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which is intended for UI testing. It is capable of generating user input events, but reading an unknown application's GUI output may be an issue.